# Generating a List and Subsequent Pages from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

In my project, I have a `JSON` file. I display the data that is parsed inside a list (`ul`) under a div with the `class`, "inner", and show only the name and cost of each product that you can see in my JSON.

```
{
 "product": [
  {
   "name": "samsung galaxy",
   "image": "https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/832/832/mobile/v/z/x/samsung-galaxy-on-nxt-sm-g610fzdgins-original-imaenkzvmnyf7sby.jpeg?q=70",
   "cost": "RS.10,000",
   "detail": "Flaunt your style with the Samsung Galaxy On Nxt. Featuring a drool-worthy body and impressive features, this smartphone is built to perform. Talk to your mom, chat with your friends, browse the Internet - stay connected the way that suits you best - this smartphone is powerful enough to keep up with your busy lifestyle."
  }
 ]
}
```

When I click on the first product (first list item), I want to show the detail (value detail) of this product in another page from that same `JSON` object; when I click on the second product, I want that to show in a different page too, but also from that same object.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jquery</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">


$.ajax({
     url: 'http://sonsofthunderstudio.in/jj/product.json',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
     type: 'get',
     crossDomain : true,
     cache: false,
     success: function(data) {
        $(data.product).each(function(index, value) {
            console.log(value);
                $( ".inner" ).append("<li>"+value.name+"<img src='" + value.image + "'  width='50px' height='50px' / >"+value.cost+"</li>");  
        });
     }
});


</script>


        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Where can I go from here?

Comment: You want to redirect to a new page which will display detail information of your product right?

Comment: @Tri yeah right

Comment: And you want to do that with pure javascript not with a server-client model?
If  you want to using javascript only, you can use @dpaksoni answer and you need another html page for display detail infomations.
If you are working with a server-client model you should send your product id to server and render your detail page from server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick event on li and call a function which will store the particular detail in localStorage.
On the next page you can access detail from localStorage and display it.

```
//--[Appending in your code]--
.
.
.
 $(data.product).each(function(index, value) {
        console.log(value);
            $( ".inner" ).append("<li onclick='foo('"+value.detail+"')'>"+value.name+"<img src='" + value.image + "'  width='50px' height='50px' / >"+value.cost+"</li>");  
    });

<script type="text/javascript">
 function foo(detail)
 {
   localStorage.setItem("DETAIL",detail);
 }
</script>


//--[On second page]--
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var detail = localStorage.getItem("DETAIL");
   $("#details").html(detail);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="details"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: i am new to javascript and jquery. can you explain it to me in a simple way, if it can be explained in an easy way.

Comment: may be with any example

Comment: i tried your code, but i think its not working. here is my files.            http://sonsofthunderstudio.in/test/index.html    and my second file for details.   http://sonsofthunderstudio.in/test/second.html

Comment: There are some errors regarding quotes. 
Try - ... onclick=\"foo("+value.detail+")\" ...

Comment: fixed them. still not working.    http://sonsofthunderstudio.in/test/index.html    http://sonsofthunderstudio.in/test/second.html

Answer (score 0):

- When you append data first you need to do is to add an `Identifier` because you need to differentiate the elements and you need to put `onClick` to each element that you will append you can put it like this: `'<li id="'+ index +'" onClick="clicklist(this)">'+ value.name (...) +'</li>'`
- The second thing you need to declare is a function called clicklist or something with the param element.
  `function clicklist(element) { }` 
  Fill it with the code I will explain now:
- You can access to your list data through the element with your jQuery functions. So first you can get id with `var id = $(element).attr('id');` then you can find your list elements and get it value with `var itemname = $(element).find("typeofelement.class").attr('value');` etc...
- When you get all data in your list you need to open a new window with the params you get in the function. Then use this code:

`//Add all the values you need in the other html (id and values) So repeat this line:
sessionStorage.setItem("ID", id); 
//Open the window
window.open("yourother.html","_blank");`

This is the simple way.

Comment: i am new to javascript and jquery. can you explain it to me in a simple way, if it can be explained in an easy way.(may be with example)

Comment: @johnlivingston Sorry about that. I'll put an edit explaining all better.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show details of your product, You have to create a "ProductList.html" to show your product list, and create a "ProductDetail.html" to show product detail based on selected product.
when user click on a product, You have to pass the selected product to "ProductDetail.html" via url and get it in that page.
the 2 "encodeURIComponenet()" and "decodeURIComponent()" are javascript defined functions to make this action encoded and safe.

To achieve this, You have to append a "Link"(A Tag) to $(".inner"):

```
$(".inner").append("<a href='#'>"+value.name+"</a>");
```

in code above, you create a link, you pass the Product ID to destination page and In codes below, You set the "href" attribute for the link:

```
var _SelectedProduct = "ID=" + ProductID;
var _EncodeID = encodeURIComponenet(_SelectedProduct);
document.getElementById("YourLink").href = "ProductDetail.html?" + _EncodeID;
```

with these codes, when user click on a product, he will be redirected to "ProductDetail.html" with the selected product ID. You can get this ID in Your ProductDetail.js:

```
var _DecodeURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location);
var ID = _DecodeURL.split("=");
var _ProductID = ID[1];
```

with these codes, you split the passed url base on ("="), which means you will get the passed Product ID.(_ProductID).
and :

```
for(i=0;i<=product.lenght; i++){
if(product[i].ID == _ProductID){ ... }
}
```

Comment: i am new to javascript and jquery. can you explain it to me in a simple way, if it can be explained in an easy way.(may be with example)

Comment: should i replace "YourLink" with "value.details"??

Comment: No, "YourLink" is an <a> tag that it's "href" attribute is "ProductDetail.html?" + _EncodeID; as I have rote in code, and it,s Text is the name of your product(value.name). So if user clicks on it, he will e redirected to Details page.

Comment: You should place the <a> tag for example after <li> tag. or <img> tag. (based on your question)